# How to remove a div containing a checkbox with a specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have different checkboxes generated dynamically.
Each checkboxes are contained within a div.

**I would like to do the following action with jquery:**

If a checkbox has an id="aucune", then remove its container (the div containing the checkbox with the id="aucune") from the html page.

**I tried the following code:**

```
// wait for DOM to be ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  var empty = $("input:checkbox[id=aucune]");
  if (empty == true) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
});
```

**Here is a the very simplified html:**

```
<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="xxx" name="xxx" date-name="xxx">
    <label for="xxx">xxx</label>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="aucune" name="aucune" date-name="aucune">
    <label for="aucune">aucune</label>
</div>
```

[Here is my codepen:](https://codepen.io/anthonysalamin/pen/yKvqPo?editors=1010)
I am quite new to code, I apologize for my silly simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly select the id with jQuery and remove the parent.

```
$('#acune').parent().remove();
```

Or  if you know the class of the parent element

```
$('#acune').parent('.wrapper-checkbox').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly referencing `this`. It should be this way:

1. Replace `this` with `empty`.
2. Replace the boolean check with count.
3. **Note:** You can also use `$("#aucune")` instead of the selector `$("input:checkbox[id=aucune]")`.

```js
// wait for DOM to be ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Or here you can also use $("#aucune").
  var empty = $("input:checkbox[id=aucune]");
  // Check if it is found.
  if (empty.length > 0) {
    // Remove the parent.
    empty.parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="xxx" name="xxx" date-name="xxx">
  <label for="xxx">xxx</label>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="aucune" name="aucune" date-name="aucune">
  <label for="aucune">aucune</label>
</div>
```

Boom! And the checkbox is gone! `:)`

Comment: thank you so much, really kind of you ! it works beautifully ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `aucune` id selector in your JQuery and then get the closest `div` with class `wrapper-checkbox` to remove it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var empty = $("#aucune");
  if (empty.length !== 0){
    $(empty).closest('.wrapper-checkbox').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="xxx" name="xxx" date-name="xxx">
    <label for="xxx">xxx</label>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" id="aucune" name="aucune" date-name="aucune">
    <label for="aucune">aucune</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkbox = $("input:checkbox[id=aucune]");
  if (checkbox.length > 0) {
    checkbox.parent().remove();
  }
});
```